# Is there a more efficient method of using the SQL count mutliple times?

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, ado, adodb

I need your help,

Is there perhaps a more efficient method to code an SQL statement to connect to the database and retrieve numerical values? My way of logic is this. Use the SQL Count to tally, store the numeric value into a var (similar to excel labelled cells), and then use the vars and output the results to an HTML table

I am wondering whether there maybe a more efficient way/method of doing so, if not am I politically correct to about the method below? I'm guessing that connecting to the DB multiple times would be somewhat slower?

I am using the Active Data Object connecting to an MS Access database (mdb file) for my own perusal.

```
var a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17
var b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17
var c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17
var d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13,d14,d15,d16,d17
var e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,e10,e11,e12,e13,e14,e15,e16,e17
var f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17
var g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,g10,g11,g12,g13,g14,g15,g16,g17
var h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10,h11,h12,h13,h14,h15,h16,h17
var i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,i10,i11,i12,i13,i14,i15,i16,i17
var j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6,j7,j8,j9,j10,j11,j12,j13,j14,j15,j16,j17

DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFAA' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
a3 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()

DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFAB' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1)+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
a4 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()

DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFAD' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
a5 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()

DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFBA' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
a7 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()

DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFBD' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
a8 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()

DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFBE' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
a9 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()

DB_connect()
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFBM' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
a10 = Number(cn.Execute(SQL).Fields(0).Value)
cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine it all into a single query:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFBA' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#") AS FirstColumn,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_imts WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET' AND [OPI]='ASFBD' AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#") AS SecondColumn,
    Add other queries here...
FROM tbl_imts
```

These are subqueries, and each subquery returns a single value you can assign to a column, so you end up with a single query that fetches all the data you're looking for.

In SQL Server you don't need the final FROM clause, but I think in Access you might.

You get your values back the same way as before:

```
rst = cn.Execute(SQL)
a1 = rst.Fields("FirstColumn").Value
a2 = rst.Fields("SecondColumn").Value
```

Set rst to be a DataSet or whatever you want to use, then just pull each field out of it.

Comment: This looks promising. How would I go about collecting the data then from the [FirstColumn] and [SecondColumn] results?

Comment: Just added that piece to my answer!

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. You've rescued a newbie from himself. I've got so much to learn with the power of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with a GROUP BY (I hope it works in Access ;-)

```
SELECT [OPI], COUNT(*) AS [CT]
FROM tbl_imts
WHERE [REQUEST TYPE]='MINISTERIAL DOCKET'
AND [OPI] IN ('ALL', 'POSSIBLE', ..) -- this line is optional
AND [DATE RECEIVED] BETWEEN #"+date1+"# AND #"+date1_2+"#"
GROUP BY [OPI]
```

In this case the `COUNT(*)` refers to the number of records *in that group*.

Then you'll get back a set of `(OPI, COUNT)` entries that you can deal with as appropriate. This can even lead to cleaner code if proper collections - such as dictionaries - are used.

The filter on `OPI` is optional, and is primarily useful if only a (small) subset of OPI values are to be counted.

Comment: This would work too, since Access does recognize the GROUP BY clause.  You would have to loop through the recordset and pull out they key (OPI) and value (CT) pairs for each row and probably put them in an array of some kind.